How to Formally Express the Probability of Feedback Being From a Bot Using Well-Defined Notation?
I encountered the following probability question in a textbook:
"$5\%$ of survey responses are from bots, which submit feedback $10$ times more often than real users. What’s the probability that a randomly selected feedback is from a bot"
I was then told that the answer was:
$$
\dfrac{10\cdot0.05}{(10\cdot0.05)+(1\cdot0.95)} \approx 35\%
$$
However, I am having a hard time giving notation to it and formally answering it. Is there a way to think about the above in rigorous notation? Thanks.

This is just an application of Bayes' theorem.
Set $B$ to be the event that the survey respondent is a bot, and $F$ to be the event that the respondent sent feedback. Set $P(F | \lnot B) = r$, i.e. the probability that a human respondent sends feedback is $r$. Then we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray} P(B) & = & 0.05 \\
P(\lnot B) & = & 0.95 \\
P(F | B) & = & 10 r \end{eqnarray}$$
You can then substitute these directly into Bayes' theorem to find $P(B | F)$, and the $r$ terms will cancel out to give the answer as given.

Thank you, what is throwing me off is the fact that $P(F | \lnot B) = r$, which seems that $r$ is a count and not probability. How can I think about it?

$r$ isn't a count, it's the fraction of responses that got feedback, and that's something we call an empirical probability because it's just asking "if we picked a random survey response from a person, with what probability would it have feedback?".
